# Sort dict of tuples by either tuple value with customised comparator

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I'm working on some python dicts of tuples. Each tuple containing 2 ints. The first digit in the tuple is reffered to as value and the second digit is referred to as work. I have 3 different comparators and I need to sort the dicts into descending order. This order should be determined by which comparator is called. i.e. the dict can be sorted 3 different ways. I've tried as many different ways as I could find to get this to work. I can do it without using the comparator by just breaking it up into a list and sorting by slicing the tuples but if anyone can shed some light on the syntax to sort using the comparators it would be greatly appreciated. Mine seems to be returning correctly for cmpWork but the other 2 aren't reversed.
  Also it would be great if I could get the dict sorted by the tuple values. 
  I got a sort working with

```
sortedSubjects = sorted(tmpSubjects.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

but this doesn't let me slice the tuples.
First time posting noob so apologies for any mistakes.

```
def cmpValue(subInfo1, subInfo2):  
    return cmp(subInfo2[0] , subInfo1[0])

def cmpWork(subInfo1, subInfo2):  
    return cmp(subInfo1[1] , subInfo2[1])  

def cmpRatio(subInfo1, subInfo2):  
    return cmp((float(subInfo2[0]) / subInfo2[1]) , (float(subInfo1[0]) / subInfo1[1]))  

def greedyAdvisor(subjects, comparator):  
    tmpSubjects = subjects.copy()  
    sortedSubjects = sorted(tmpSubjects.values(), comparator, reverse = True)   
    print sortedSubjects  


smallCatalog = {'6.00': (16, 8),'1.00': (7, 7),'6.01': (5, 3),'15.01': (9, 6)}  
greedyAdvisor(smallCatalog, cmpRatio)  
greedyAdvisor(smallCatalog, cmpValue)  
greedyAdvisor(smallCatalog, cmpWork)  

[(7, 7), (9, 6), (5, 3), (16, 8)]  
[(5, 3), (7, 7), (9, 6), (16, 8)]  
[(16, 8), (7, 7), (9, 6), (5, 3)]
```

ps
The line

```
sortedSubjects = sorted(tmpSubjects.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

returns

```
[('6.00', (16, 8)), ('15.01', (9, 6)), ('1.00', (7, 7)), ('6.01', (5, 3))]
```

which is almost exactly what I'm looking for except that I can't sort by the second value in the tuple and I can't sort by cmpRatio either.

Comment: Hint: `sorted` returns a new list; no need to create `tmpSubjects`. You could return the result of `sorted` straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this doesn't let me slice the tuples

Starting with your example:

```
sortedSubjects = sorted(tmpSubjects.iteritems(),
                        key=operator.itemgetter(1),
                        cmp=comparator,   # What about specifying the comparison?
                        reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks folks. I wasn't aware that I had to import collections to use odereddict so thanks for that and I left the cmp keyword out of my sort statement. Only spotted it when I read Ricardos answer.  When I added it in it worked properly. Thanks volcano and Ricardo. Will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort dictionary - use collections.OrderedDict
E.g., sort by 1st element of tuple

```
 OrderedDict(sorted(smallCatalog.items(), key=lambda e:e[1][0]))
Out[109]: OrderedDict([('6.01', (5, 3)), ('1.00', (7, 7)), ('15.01', (9, 6)), ('6.00', (16, 8))])
```